# OpenVPN client reconnecting due to --ping-restart even if traffic is flowing both ways

Tags: openvpn

The situation:

- An OpenVPN (2.3.12) server with public IP `1.1.1.1` running in Amazon EC2, using the UDP protocol.
- A remote OpenVPN (2.3.10) client with public IP `2.2.2.2`, somewhere on an ADSL connection and behind a wifi home router and firewall.

The problem is that the client keeps reconnecting, once every 40 seconds, even though the connection appears to be working fine.

As you can see below, we have `keepalive 10 40` configured on the server, and this is duly pushed to the client. I can change the value, but of course we *do* want the client to reconnect if the connection is *actually* broken (e.g. the wifi router was restarted and forgot all its stateful UDP rules). So that's not a good option.

The disconnect happens even if I `ssh` onto the client through the VPN and generate some traffic both ways by e.g. scrolling up and down in `less`, or if I run a continuous `ping` to the client through the VPN.

We also had trouble with packet loss being caused by MTU size, but that's been fixed by using `mssfix 1200` on the client. For the record, the client can ping the server (outside the VPN) using

```
ping -M do -s 1412 -c 1 1.1.1.1
```

So our `mssfix` value can theoretically be set to 1372 according to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/841417/14335); 1200 is just to add a safety margin (and so we can reuse this config on other clients on other networks).

From the client log:

```
[server] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
TCP/UDP: Closing socket
SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Re-using SSL/TLS context
LZO compression initialized
Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1200 EF:58 EB:143 ET:0 EL:3 AF:3/1 ]
Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
Local Options hash (VER=V4): '22188c5b'
Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'a8f55717'
UDPv4 link local: [undef]
UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]1.1.1.1:1194
TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]1.1.1.1:1194, sid=78ff051d c8d027a7
VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=REDACTED
Validating certificate key usage
++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 00a0
VERIFY KU OK
Validating certificate extended key usage
++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
VERIFY EKU OK
VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
[server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]1.1.1.1:1194
SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 10.84.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 40,ifconfig 10.84.0.6 255.255.0.0'
OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tun0
Initialization Sequence Completed
```

From the server log:

```
MULTI: multi_create_instance called
93.254.95.157:33098 Re-using SSL/TLS context
93.254.95.157:33098 LZO compression initialized
93.254.95.157:33098 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
93.254.95.157:33098 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1450 EF:58 EB:143 ET:0 EL:3 AF:3/1 ]
93.254.95.157:33098 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
93.254.95.157:33098 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
93.254.95.157:33098 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'a8f55717'
93.254.95.157:33098 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '22188c5b'
93.254.95.157:33098 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]93.254.95.157:33098, sid=a3383b01 bc17f487
93.254.95.157:33098 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=REDACTED
93.254.95.157:33098 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=ClientName
93.254.95.157:33098 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
93.254.95.157:33098 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
93.254.95.157:33098 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
93.254.95.157:33098 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
93.254.95.157:33098 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
93.254.95.157:33098 [ClientName] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]93.254.95.157:33098
MULTI: new connection by client 'ClientName' will cause previous active sessions by this client to be dropped.  Remember to use the --duplicate-cn option if you want multiple clients using the same certificate or username to concurrently connect.
MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.84.0.6, IPv6=(Not enabled)
MULTI: Learn: 10.84.0.6 -> ClientName/2.2.2.2:33098
MULTI: primary virtual IP for ClientName/2.2.2.2:33098: 10.84.0.6
ClientName/2.2.2.2:33098 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
ClientName/2.2.2.2:33098 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
ClientName/2.2.2.2:33098 SENT CONTROL [ClientName]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 10.84.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 40,ifconfig 10.84.0.6 255.255.0.0' (status=1)
```

Client configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 1.1.1.1 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 4
mssfix 1200
```

Server configuration:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.84.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
keepalive 10 40
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
```

I might be able to fix this by switching to TCP instead of UDP, but I'm wary of the overhead and [risks](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html), and feel that it's a silly "solution" even if it ends up working.

Any other ideas on where to look and what to try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You know what helps? Not running two `openvpn` client processes on the client machine at the same time. The first one would reconnect, and at that point the server forgets about the second one and stops pinging it, so the second one eventually reconnects, and so on...

I feel a bit silly now, but I'm leaving this up in case someone else is being similarly silly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue by running two clients with the same client name (CN) on different machines. To fix it I've created different clients pet machine.